# ASP.Net double URL Rewriting

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I am using URL Rewriting to make my URLs more understandable(well, thats why it is used mostly).
But I would like to further rewrite them to make them even more understandable.
My home page is at /Pages/1/Home.aspx after rewriting with the below rule.

```
<rewrite url="~/Pages/(.+)/(.+).aspx" to="~/MainTemplate_$1.aspx?PageName=$2"/>
```

But I suppose it doesn't look good, at least for home page. So I have applied below rule again.

```
<rewrite url="~/index.aspx" to="~/Pages/41/Home.aspx"></rewrite>
```

But that doesn't work. Redirect instead of rewrite works, but the address bar would show clunky details which I don't want.
How do I make it work?
Thanks!

Comment: Never mind! Just had to change the rule order. Its working fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had to rearrange the rule order to get it working. Pretty straight forward.